# ForEach multiply issue

Tags: php, foreach

This is probably a stupid gotcha that I'm overlooking but I'm hoping one of you can help me!
I've got a loop to list a grid of Products in my DB.

So far so good, everything is displaying roughly OK except this one little issue.

Within a list I'm doing the following:

```
<ul>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($products as $product) : $i++; ?>
    <li  <?php 
            if(($i%4) ==0){

                echo 'class="last"';
              } elseif($i%2==0){
                  echo 'class="second"';
              } 
          ?>>

// Then I've got the image thumbnail etc coming in....
```

All looks good except for the LAST row...

So for instance if I have 8 products... the first 7 will display on the page correctly, but then there is a gap at the end where the 8th product moves onto the next page.

At first I thought it was CSS widths or something but it's not. Even if I have 20 products...always the last row only shows 3 across and puts the last product on the next page.

Any ideas anyone?

Cheers M

Comment: Can you provide a link, or at least the HTML markup that is being created?

Comment: sounds more like CSS than PHP - are you sure 'class="last"' is valid and correct?

Comment: Start the incrementation at 1 instead of 0 so `$i=1;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <?php $i=count($products); ?>
    <li  
       <?php 
            if(($i%4) ==0){
                   echo 'class="last"';
              } elseif($i%2==0){
                  echo 'class="second"';
              } 
       ?>>
```

Let's try it..

Comment: Probably would help if it actually looped.

Comment: Hiya, THanks for your reply. No that didnt work, some syntax error. 

Here is the actual page.
http://www.kochtail.de/index.php?route=product/productall